# execve(2) system commands exit before execution

Tags: c, linux, namespaces

I am trying to implement a container, and for that I create a process using the clone(2) system call with the appropriate flags:

```
  if ((child_pid = clone(child_main, process_struct.Stack + process_struct.StackPtr,
   CLONE_NEWCGROUP
  |CLONE_NEWIPC
  |CLONE_NEWNET
  |CLONE_NEWNS
  |CLONE_NEWPID
  |CLONE_NEWUTS
  |SIGCHLD, &process_struct, checkpoint)) == -1){
     fprintf(stderr,"Failed...%m \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  }else{
    fprintf(stderr,"Done\n");
    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
  }
```

inside child_main() I Change the host name for the process's namespace, also i set the mount namespace, I installed a Linux file system hierarchy on a partition like a normal Linux installation (I did that to create a clean file system image clean of my files and binaries) and then I set the propagation type to MS_UNBINDABLE, then I pivot_root(2) to change my process's root directory.

```
const int child_main(struct process *process_struct, int *checkpoint){

  char c;
  fprintf(stderr,"=> IPC setup...");
  //double check the IPC
  close(checkpoint[1]);
  fprintf(stderr,"Done\n");

  if ( sethostname(process_struct->Hostname, 
strlen(process_struct->Hostname)) || mounting(process_struct)){
    return -1;
  }

  // startup the IPC pipes
  read(checkpoint[0], &c, 1);

  if(execve("/bin/bash", (char*)0, NULL) == -1 ){
    fprintf(stderr,"--> Launching process Failed %m\n");
    return -1;
  }
    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that my system goes over the execve(2) and does not launch the /bin/bash and the program flows without errors. When I add system(2) statement before the execve(2) : `system("ls");` it lists the appropriate file system and current working directory. Also when I change the execve(2) paramters to either: 
`execve("/bin/ls", (char*)0, NULL)` or `execve("/bin/pstree", (char*)0, NULL)` or any other parameter it will return an error of: **No such file or directory** or **A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call**, also when I strace my program at the execve(2) system call it gives: **NULL, 0, NULL)             = 17992**

The error has nothing to do with the file system image, I have performed more tests and are as the follwoing, I used for my mount namespaces my system's filesystem not the one I installed on a partition and running /bin/bash doesn't still work, I created a simple C program and compiled it, and it ran fine so there is something wrong that prevent bin/bash from being executed, to further test these results I reused for my mount namespaces the file system from my I moved the same executable to the file system first under `"/"` and second under the same path
**my main system path to the executable=** `/home/omar/docs/test.out`
**my mounted file system from the partition path to the executable=** `/home/omar/docs/test.out` 
since I wanted to check if the same path might have caused a confusion while adding to each executable a statment so can tell which path did my program take, and it worked fine without any problem and correctly as expected, so the problem is just that system essential commands will not work.

Comment: The second argument to `execve()` can't be a null pointer, it has to be a pointer to a null-terminated array.

Comment: And that array needs at least one element, `argv[0]` must be the name of the program.

Comment: The third argument also has to be a pointer to an array, not `NULL`.

Comment: Do you really want the child process to have empty environment variables? If you don't need to specify the environment, and want it to inherit the current environment, use `execv` instead of `execve`.

Comment: Use `perror()` to print the error from a system call.

Comment: I added to my code the following as args just to test ```/bin/bash```, I created an arguments array ```char *argv = {"/bin/bash",(char*)0};``` and I added my systems env variables via ```extern char **environ; char **ep = environ;``` then I changed my execve to ```if(execve("/bin/bash", argv, ep)  == -1 ){
    //printf("--> Launching process Failed %s\n", strerror(errno));
    perror("The following occured");
    return -1;
  }``` that gave me Bad address error.

Comment: before changing the code I used ```perror()``` and nothing was printed. so the system call was successful

Comment: I also tried the ```execv(3)``` with the correct string of arguments as you suggested and it gave me bad address error

Comment: It should be `char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash",(char*)0};`

Comment: yes I just fixed it and the Bad address error was fixed but still even after passing the environment variables to the child my process dies directly after ```execve(2)```, returning to the question's main issue.

Comment: I used all ```execv(3)``` ```execvp(3)``` ```execve(2)``` to test this out

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a proper `argv` array to `execve`. And if you just want to pass on the current environment, use `execv` rather than `execve`.

```
char *argv[] = {"bash", NULL};
if(execv("/bin/bash", argv) == -1 ){
    perror("execv");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: the process still dies without doing anything.

Comment: How is its standard input connected? Maybe it's reading EOF and exiting normally.

Comment: same that happens in the original question.

Comment: right now I am making the executable and arguments strings just as the question, so there is no input, if this is an irrelevant answer tell me how to test my standard input connectivity, also when I add any a.out executable to my mount namespace it works just fine without any problems.

Comment: So this works with a random `a.out`, but not with `/bin/bash`?

Comment: yes, also I tested the ```/bin/bash``` out of my program and out of namespaces and it launches terminal fine so ```/bin/bash``` is not corrupted, I also did this on other system commands residing on the file system partition I created solely for my container , and none works from within my namespace.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the container, not your syntax for calling `execve`. Maybe something to do with shared libraries?

Comment: how can I investigate that problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm not familiar with the container stuff you're using.